# Connection is established hive wd Hue but unable to read data

Tags: hive, hue

I tried integrating hive with hue connection is made but getting following error
TSocket read 0 bytes

I checked hive and hue configurations everthing is correct ports are listening ,hiveserver and metastore is running but dont know why hue is unable to read hive data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im trying to connect Hive with Hue ,both are running in same server ,connection from hive wd Hue is done but unable to read the database from Hive  in HUE